# Why is the prohibition against one man murdering another considered a "mitzvah sichlis", while fish and animals may prey on each other?

Tags: taamei-mitzvot-reasons

Why is The prohibition against one man murdering another [רציחה] considered a "***mitzvah sichlis***", a logically understood mitzvah,  (as quoted in שמונה פרקים להרמב"ם פרק ו) while fish and animals may prey on each other?

since Hashem created the world as such that certain living creatures prey on others to sustain themselves, this must not be something bad.
Why is it more logical that it is bad for a man to kill another man, than it is for a fish to kill another fish, or an animal to kill another animal?

Comment: Are you asking why any sane person is born with a disgust at killing a fellow man? Btw, animals don't eat the same species afaik. That's the difference.

Comment: 1- Sichli is not a matter of "disgust" Disgust is emotion, I was referring to logic 2- AFAIK certain fish definitely do eat their own species. And if there were 2 species of man would you think differently about them murdering one another?

Comment: it's also sichli that humans are higher than animals who lack a true sechel

Answer (score 3):

I would think that the idea of a "mitzvah sichlis" as you call it is that such mitzvos have obvious benefit to man even without any concept of religion. Specifically, these are the mitzvos which form the framework of a functioning society, and indeed most (if not all) societies, even non-religious ones, have laws about murder, theft, adultery, etc.

The idea, then, is that man can logically arrive at the conclusion that certain actions (e.g. murder) impede the proper function of society and are therefore inherently "bad". Not necessarily "bad" as in a moral judgement, but "bad" in a practical framework.

As such there would be no reason for a parallel construct with animals and fish. Animals and fish can't contemplate the sophisticated ideas involved in determining what would lead to a functional or dysfunctional society, they don't actually have "society" in the sense that humans have, and even to whatever extent that they do have "society" it is not for the most part impeded by preying on other groups of animals (much like human society is not much impeded by preying on animals).